# Installer generated with jpackage on Windows creates not-runnable executable

Tags: java, windows-installer, jpackage

I use jpackage to pack jar file to windows installer:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin\jpackage"
--name test-installer
--input .
--main-jar test.jar
--runtime-image ../jre1.8.0_341/
--main-class com.xxxxx.Main
--win-console
```

which gives me test-installer.exe. After installation, the executable could not be run.

Console output gives:

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

If it helps, here is WinDbg output

```
************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff6`7b7d0000 00007ff6`7b841000   jpackageapplauncher.exe
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7d980000 00007ffa`7db89000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7cf90000 00007ffa`7d04d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7b0e0000 00007ffa`7b45c000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7c950000 00007ffa`7cafd000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7ae60000 00007ffa`7ae86000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7d4a0000 00007ffa`7d4c9000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7b6f0000 00007ffa`7b809000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7b5d0000 00007ffa`7b66d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7af00000 00007ffa`7b011000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7c040000 00007ffa`7c7f8000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
(3eb4.dfbc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffa`7da5cef4 cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7d1f0000 00007ffa`7d221000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7c800000 00007ffa`7c8ea000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7b990000 00007ffa`7ba2e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`79f50000 00007ffa`79f68000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`7d140000 00007ffa`7d1e3000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14:
00007ffa`7da24104 c3              ret
```

I do not understand, what does jpackage here?
Installer made with trial version of install4j works.

What am I doing wrong? Please any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `jpackage` command you're using, it looks like you are trying to use a Java 8 JRE as a runtime image:

```
--runtime-image ../jre1.8.0_341/
```

This is not possible. As you've found it results in a broken runtime image that fails to launch. The Java 8 JRE is just not designed to be used this way.

In general, the runtime image passed to `--runtime-image` should be made with the `jlink` tool from the same JDK as `jpacakge`.

Comment: Does jpackage on macOs do it differently? I also passed to --runtime-image jre1.8.0 (macOs version) to create .pkg installer. In that case the app starts normally.

Comment: @aermolov It depends on the JRE. AFAIK the Java 8 Windows JRE depends on a bunch of registry keys being set when the JRE is installed, in order for the launcher to find the installation directory, but that doesn't happen if you package it up with `jpacakge` and run the resulting installer.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin\jlink --module-path jre1.8.0_341 --add-modules java-base --output customRuntime` makes for me an image of runtime-image with version 17.0.0. How can I tell jlink to use jre1.8.0?

Comment: @aermolov You can't. Java 8 JREs are not designed to be repackaged like this. That support was introduced with Java 9 (through `jlink`).